sharing a link with the Facebook sharer.php URL does not use OG:IMAGE metatags
Our websites have share button on them that uses the Facebook sharer URL, for example:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.allazhomes.com%2F7-ways-to-get-top-dollar-for-your-home%3Fsharing%3D1149899

Very often, the Facebook window that opens up does not include the page image, description, etc - just the link and a message "Say something about this...". The open graph tags are pretty well-populated:
<meta property="og:site_name" content="allazhomes.com" data-react-helmet="true"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="7 Ways to Get Top Dollar for Your Home" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="When it comes to selling your home, everyone wants to maximize their return. Getting top dollar for your property doesn't happen by chance—it requires strategic planning, effective marketing, and a keen understanding of the real estate market. At Heart ..." data-react-helmet="true" />

<meta property="og:url" itemprop="url" content="https://www.allazhomes.com/7-ways-to-get-top-dollar-for-your-home" data-react-helmet="true" />

<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://idx-acnt-ihouseprd.b-cdn.net/AR1149899/file_manager/Blog/top%20dollar.png?width=800&height=600" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://idx-acnt-ihouseprd.b-cdn.net/AR1149899/file_manager/Blog/top%20dollar.png?width=800&height=600" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600" data-react-helmet="true" />

Sometimes it works and the image shows up, but much of the time, it does not. This is terribly annoying, and I need to figure out how to make this work. Using the Link Debugger is not an option, these are dynamically generated pages and I have no idea how to figure out when someone might want to share a page. Any thoughts?
thanks in advance,
andy
